# how quasiquotes are represented in syntax tree (CL)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming, quasiquotes

I understand how quotes are represented in language:

```
(equal ''(1 2) (list 'quote (list 1 2))) ;; => T
```

but what about quasi-quotes? is it something like:

```
(equal ``(1 2) (list '<???> (list 1 2)))
```

Both `quasiquote` and `backquote` instead of `<???>` don't work.

Comment: Maybe you will find the answer in the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm)

Comment: have you tried `quote`? it works in CLISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard representation in Common Lisp.  What backquote should *do* is specified, but there is no equivalent to `quote`.  In particular the spec says in [2.4.6](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm), after giving the specification of how backquote should behave:

> An implementation is free to interpret a backquoted form F1 as any form F2 that, when evaluated, will produce a result that is the same under equal as the result implied by the above definition, provided that the side-effect behavior of the substitute form F2 is also consistent with the description given above.

Note that this is not in fact a problem since backquote is a thing you can implement yourself, while `quote` needs to be in the guts of the language.

Comment: That text is misusing the word "form" in "backquoted form". A form is an object to be evaluated. No object is a backquoted-anything; that's read syntax, or an *expression* (in sense 2, as given by the Glossary).

Comment: @Kaz: I think what it means by 'backquoted form' is what it describes earlier as a 'form denoted by `[...]' (my ellipsis), which as you say is a sense-2 expression.  But, well, that's what was written.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there is no representation required:

```
 '`(1 2) -> '(1 2)

 '`(,1 2) -> '(1 2)

 '`(,a 2) -> (list* a '(2))
```

Implementations may expand into special constructs, so that backquote expressions can also be printed as backquote expressions.